# Create object from XML string in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, ruby, activerecord

I am trying to deserialize an object from XML in Ruby.

Something simple like:

```
u = User.new({:client_key => "Bar"})
v = User.new(u.to_xml)
```

I get an error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method 'stringify_keys!' for #String:0x20fc7cc>

I'm not sure what I have to do in order to get the string from XML to an object.

**Update:**  @avdi gave me the tip.  I was expecting from_xml to be a self method.  You have to create the object first.

```
v = User.new
v.from_xml(s)
```

Comment: This is a Rails/ActiveRecord question, not a Ruby question (to_xml is not part of Ruby).  Re-tagged accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick search turns up http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Serialization.html#M001420